# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 26 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

I would appreciate some help. I have used this before and it worked fine. I tried to use it in a new app and it breaks. I understand it is a problem with the index, but I can't pin point it.

```
    self.greensArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    [self.greensArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }


letterIndex =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *name = [searchViewArray valueForKey:@"meatName"];
for (int i = 0; i < [name count]; ++i) {
    NSUInteger firstLetter = [ALPHA rangeOfString:[[name objectAtIndex:i ] substringToIndex:1]].location;
    [self.greensArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray array] atIndex:i];
    if (firstLetter != NSNotFound) {
        [[self.greensArray objectAtIndex:firstLetter] addObject:[name objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    char alphabet = [[name objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
    NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",alphabet];
    if(![letterIndex containsObject:uniChar])
    {
        [letterIndex addObject:uniChar];

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for firstLetter to exceed 25 or the current bounds of greensArray?

Comment: What line is generating the crash?

Comment: This is the code generating the crash --   [[self.beefArray objectAtIndex:firstLetter] addObject:[name objectAtIndex:i]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here: [self.greensArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray array] atIndex:i];
I don't know why this worked in my first application, but this line of code added additional values to the greensArray. That threw off the integer / meatName count and made the whole app crash.

Comment: To be more specific, when I say that it threw off the [Name count] I mean that it add additional values to the count. So, when the app is looking for 26 values it received more, 136 to me exact.